# Vb.Net get radio 1s nowplaying from json file in windows form

Tags: json, vb.net, winforms, internet-radio

Now I am making a radio program and ive come across this http://www.bbc.co.uk/radio1/developers/api/ but I have now idea how to implement it in to my program. It's using a .json file. I know how to do it using php but I shows a loads stuff I don't need nor know how to use. and I don't want to host a php page because the hosting I have is slow some times and a constant pinging will make it slower. so is there any way to do it in the program. i will be grabbing the .json from the bbc page. And the json things are "artist":, "image":  and "title": 
Thank you in advance.
oh im still in secondary school so im not a pro in vb.net

Answer (score 0):

Try using json.net (http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) to parse the data into .Net classes and then use the resulting objects in your VB application.

Comment: how do i load the external file that is (www.bbc.co.uk/radio1/nowplaying/latest.json) on a timer to make it update automatically

Comment: Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx to see if that helps. If you're still stuck, try posting some code that you've tried and the problems you've run into. That will typically get you a better response on this forum.